# missing '/usr/share/plymouth/themes/details': No such file or directory when upgrading packages

Tags: apt, dpkg, 19.10, plymouth, initramfs

I on Ubuntu 19.10 with kernel version 5.46(latest i guess) using KDE plasma 5.18 DE.

I get the error `cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/plymouth/themes/details': No such file or directory` when running `apt upgrade`. However I think it was done by me non-intentionally when I ran `sudo rm -r /usr/share/plymouth/themes/*` and `sudo rm -r /lib/plymouth/themes/*` in order remove all plymouth themes. How ever they were not removed in that way so I removed them using `sudo apt remove plymouth-theme*`, so it removed the themes installed using apt. Then I installed some custom plymouth themes and some in the repositories and configured them using `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`. And the next problem is the plymouth theme doesn't show up when starting or shutting down. I think it is because I have broke the plymouth system by deleting the files. What should I do?

Here is the full error message.

```
sakithbk@Sakith-Laptop:~$ sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for sakithbk: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  metasploit-framework (ignore this)
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.133ubuntu10) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.133ubuntu10) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-46-generic
cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/plymouth/themes/details': No such file or directory (<-- here)
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/plymouth failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-46-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**

Forgot to mention my intention of removing the themes. I had a problem where some plymouth themes doesn't work properly that the configured(the one selected by me) theme is showed during startup and another one(a text plymouth theme) is showed during shutdown. So I thought it will be fixed If I remove and reinstall them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reinstall the corresponding packages with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall \
$(dpkg -S /usr/share/plymouth/themes/details | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | sed "s/://")
```

and also reinstall all packages mentioned in the output of

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/plymouth/
```